# HTML Parsing by PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, xpath

I am trying to parse the tender information (Department, location, Ref No, Closing Date, Description and the Urls (for attachment/downloadable pdf) for tender files) in an array from the following site
http://www.biman-airlines.com/corporate/tender

i am a newbie and dont know how to do it. i tried the following which is not working

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.biman-airlines.com/corporate/tender";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);


$headerNames = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//table[@id=""]//th') as $node) {
$headerNames[] = $node->nodeValue;
}


$data = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//tbody[@id=""]//tr') as $node) {
$rowData = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('td', $node) as $cell) {
    $rowData[] = $cell->nodeValue;
}

$data[] = array_combine($headerNames, $rowData);
}

print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: Please share some more info: whats not working? what errors did you get and what have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. See if it helps.

```
    $url = "http://www.biman-airlines.com/corporate/tender";

    /* Use internal libxml errors -- turn on in production, off for debugging */
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    /* Createa a new DomDocument object */
    $dom = new DomDocument;
    /* Load the HTML */
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
    /* Create a new XPath object */
    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
    /* Query all <td> nodes containing specified class name */
    $nodes = $xpath->query("//th");
    /* Set HTTP response header to plain text for debugging output */
    // header("Content-type: text/plain");

    /* Traverse the DOMNodeList object to output each DomNode's nodeValue */
    foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
        if(($i % 10) == 0)
        echo "Node($i): ", $node->nodeValue, "\n" . "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: works perfectly fine. Thank you so much. How can i divide the node values in array? like in node 0------Node(0): 1 Department: Corporate Planning Location: Dhaka Ref.No: DACPM/Q400/173/2017/529 Closing Date: 21 NOV 2017 ----from this i want to keep department , location, refno and closing date in a array variable to insert in to a database. –

Comment: Use explode. Or, look at Other elements in the array without the %10. That can get you indivdual details.  Please do upvote if you like the answer.

Comment: how can i also catch the description part and the urls under $nodes?? thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Showcases a horizontal menu that hides at
     small window widths, and which scrolls when revealed.">
    <title>Responsive Horizontal-to-Scrollable Menu &ndash; Layout Examples &ndash; Pure</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/lib
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-41480445-1', 'purecss.io');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
</head>
<body>





<style>
.custom-menu-wrapper {
    background-color: white<!--#808080-->;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
}

.custom-menu {
background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.custom-menu .pure-menu-link,
.custom-menu .pure-menu-heading {
    color: black;
}

.custom-menu .pure-menu-link:hover,
.custom-menu .pure-menu-heading:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.custom-menu-top {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

.custom-menu-brand {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.custom-menu-toggle {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}

.custom-menu-toggle .bar {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 12px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.custom-menu-toggle .bar:first-child {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
    transform: translateY(-9px);
}

.custom-menu-toggle.x .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.custom-menu-toggle.x .bar:first-child {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.custom-menu-screen {
    background-color:white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.custom-menu-tucked .custom-menu-screen {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
    transform: translateY(-44px);
}
.sizee{
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-bottom: -1%;
    }
@media (max-width: 90em) {

    .custom-menu {
        display: block;

    }

    .custom-menu-toggle {
        display: block;
        display: none\9;
    }

    .custom-menu-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid #eee;
        background-color: white\9;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .custom-menu-bottom .pure-menu-link {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .custom-menu-bottom.custom-menu-tucked .pure-menu-link {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-140px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-140px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-140px);
        transform: translateX(-140px);
        opacity: 0;
        opacity: 1\9;
    }

    .pure-menu-horizontal.custom-menu-tucked {
        z-index: -1;
        top: 45px;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
    @media (max-width: 60em) {
    .sizee{
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-bottom: -1%;
    }
    }

</style>
<div>
<div class="custom-menu-wrapper navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="pure-menu custom-menu custom-menu-top">
        <a href="" class="pure-menu-heading custom-menu-brand"><img class="sizee" src='bhagat.jpg'></a>
        <a href="#" class="custom-menu-toggle" id="toggle"><s class="bar"></s><s class="bar"></s></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-scrollable custom-menu custom-menu-bottom custom-menu-tucked" id="tuckedMenu" style='border: inherit;'>
        <div class="custom-menu-screen"></div>
        <center>
        <ul class="pure-menu-list">
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">GitHub</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Twitter</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Apple</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Google</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Wang</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Yahoo</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">W3C</a></li>
        </ul>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
(function (window, document) {
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('tuckedMenu').classList.toggle('custom-menu-tucked');
    document.getElementById('toggle').classList.toggle('x');
});
})(this, this.document);
</script>


<style>
.main {
    padding: 2em;
    color: black;
}
</style>

<div class="main">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```